Help with Ventilation Controller (not sure what it does?)
I moved into a new house and our HVAC has something on it called a Ventilation Contoller, picture is below:
https://imgur.com/kOzXJkh

The problem is I have no idea what this does, or how to test it. I think it's some sort of fresh air ventilation system? When I put it in "Test" mode it doesn't do anything. I have searched everywhere on Google to find some sort of manual on this, but the single post I could find on this is an ebay listing which still doesn't give me any information.
Can somebody help me understand what exactly this does, or what I can do to test it? Is this thing so out of date that I could update it with a new one?
The furnace unit I have is a Goodman, and it has an Aprilaire 500m Humidifier attached to it.
Appreciate any help with this.

It is a system that brings fresh air into the house instead of just circulating air like most residential HVAC systems.  It consists of this controller, a duct from outside to the return air plenum, a valve to turn that duct on and off, and some sensors - outdoor temp, humidity.  Based on its program, your settings, and the sensor data it sometimes opens the valve while the HVAC system is running to admit fresh air.
Here is a link to a more recent version of it, where you can find further documentation that may or may not apply to your older system.
The motorized air intake valve ought to be relatively easy to find if your main system and ductwork is in an unfinished basement.  Look for an air duct with an electric motor stuck on.

It may simply be controlling a fresh air intake, not a HRV nor ERV. No heat exchange, just suck in some outside air. That's a more basic and cheaper function than HRVs/ERVs.
Look for a (typically small) duct connected to the outside, somewhere on the return plenum.
The controller would do something like operating a damper that causes fresh air to be added to the house by sucking it into the return, evidently for a set number of minutes per heating cycle. So when you "test" it, the damper should operate, if that's what it's doing. That won't make much noise, so you'll probably need to find it and look to see if it's working.

This is a Heat Recovery Ventilation control. In modern homes, it is required to ensure that the Humidity remains in a set range by warming or cooling the air it brings into the house.
There should be a box somewhere which has 4 insulated pipes attached, 2 to the inside ductwork and 2 to the exterior. The box contains a heat exchanger that recovers some of the inside temperature difference while bringing fresh air into the house. If the control is to on you should hear a fan working inside the unit.
There are a series of plates inside the unit that should be cleaned regularly to ensure proper operation.

Interesting, I don't see that unit anywhere. When I turn it to "Test" I don't hear any fans come on either.  Is it possible the furnace was updated and this got disconnected? I checked and the furnace looks like it was manufactured in 2020 (Goodman CAPF4860C6).
I don't see any other units near the furnace and it's not in our attic or anywhere else in the basement.  The cords that are connected from the control unit go into the bottom of my furnace.

It's also possible that this controller was installed in place of a humidistat.
